# How to fix "operation not permitted" on ssh login?

Tags: ssh

My previously fine working ssh login now results in a "Operation not permitted" error *after* getting a connection accepted. I can't think of anything I changed except for restarting the server, so what could have gone wrong?

Here's the relevant log:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Operation not permitted
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to horst closed.
```

Comment: Wild guess: the remote side's "login setup" (.bashrc et al.) scripts have a bug, so the shell terminates immediately. Does the remote user have sufficient access to their home directory?

Comment: In the server, try to ssh to a localhost. Does it work? How about `scp` from the client?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I tried temporarily renaming `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`, to no avail. Access to the home directory is possible (via telnet, it's a NAS). Things worked fine until I rebooted, so I assume I screwed up something in `sshd_config`, but I can't remember having changed anything there...

Comment: @JariLaamanen `scp` from the client fails with "Operation not permitted" as well. I'm afraid a truly "local" `ssh` is not possible since this is an NAS, and now the only way to access it is via some [telnet exploit](http://buffalo.nas-central.org/wiki/Category%3aLS-WVL)...

Comment: I put up a minimal `.profile` with `echo test`, which is never displayed

Comment: Are you by any means using `sftponly`? If yes, you might take a look at http://forum.buffalo.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=22588

Comment: @JariLaamanen Not on purpose :-7 But yes, this was the issue (I have added root to one of the groups that had `allowssh no`) and also hints at my other problem of only-root-can-login as well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you found the solution! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has [hinted at by Jari Laamanen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47335/how-to-fix-operation-not-permitted-on-ssh-login#comment65884_47335), the solution lies in [this buffalo.nas-central.org thread](http://forum.buffalo.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=22588):

I have added `root` to a new group, which happend to be blocked from ssh access in the file `/etc/sftponly`. As pointed out in that thread, changing this file is only permanent if the line `nas_configgen -c sftp` is commented out in `/etc/init.d/sshd.sh`.

Comment: as a side-note, to allow non-root users acces, [this thread](http://forum.buffalo.nas-central.org/viewtopic.php?p=133483#p133483) provides many hints. Most important: Take care of user home directories, and add `UsePriviledgeSeparation no` to `/etc/sshd_config`. Setting `/etc/profile`'s permissions may also be required

Answer (score 0):

Add the sshd-keygen-wrapper to :
The system settings;
Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to note _why_ you think this will solve the OPs problem.