# ssh: connect to host ipaddress port 22: Operation not permitted

Tags: centos, ssh

I've installed CentOs 7 on my server and trying to connect to it by `ssh ipaddress` but I get following error: `ssh: connect to host 172.20.2.74 port 22: Operation not permitted`

In order to solve this error I have done these solution:

1. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have set `PermitRootLogin` to `yes`
2. I've [created new user](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-centos-quickstart) and tried to ssh by `ssh newuser@ipaddress`

But No matter what I do, I always get the same error and couldn't find anything helpful in net.

Is there somthing that I'm missing there, maybe somthing in `sshd_config`?

**Update**
Due to @Rabban comment.. I added `-vvv` to ssh command and here's the result:

```
$ ssh -vvv ipaddress
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ipaddress" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ipaddress [ipaddress] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ipaddress port 22: Operation not permitted
ssh: connect to host ipaddress port 22: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Are you sure that `sshd` is running on the machine? what is the result of running `ssh localhost` from the machine to itself?

Comment: Related: [How to fix "operation not permitted" on ssh login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47335/117516)

Comment: @SatoKatsura I've checked that question. nothing there was helpful

Comment: @Yaron I've ran ssh by `service sshd start`

Comment: Try sshing with the `-vvv` flag and append the output to your question. The relevant section of `journalctl -u sshd` couldn't hurt either.

Comment: @Rabban The first part is done. As for the second part of your comment I have no idea what did you mean!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's foolish or what, but maybe this experience help someone else later.

The problem was solved when I disabled my firewall in remote system (*Cuz i'm trying `ssh` via `git bash` in windows*). And I can connect by `root`  and `newuser` now.